# Differentiability Implies Continuity Twist

Tags: real-analysis

In every proof I have seen of this, one manipulates the definition of continuity (a function $f$ is continuous at a point $a$ if the value of the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is $f(a)$) to prove the result.

I am wondering if somebody can help me reach this same conclusion by specifying a delta value using the full definition of limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in\mathbb R$ there is some $L=f'(x)\in\mathbb R$ with

$$\forall \epsilon >0,\,\exists\delta>0,\,\forall h \text{ with } 0<|h|<\delta ,\, \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-L\right|<\epsilon$$

Now, the last inequality can be manipulated to yield

\begin{align}
|f(x+h)-f(x)|-|Lh|
&\leq\Big||f(x+h)-f(x)|-|Lh|\Big|&\\
&\leq|f(x+h)-f(x)-Lh|&<\epsilon|h|
\end{align}

which implies that

$$|f(x+h)-f(x)|<|h|\,(\epsilon + |L|)<\delta\,(|L|+\epsilon)$$

We need to choose $\delta$ suitable so that $\delta\, (|L|+\epsilon)\leq \epsilon$.
It suffices to take $\delta\leq \frac{\epsilon}{|L|+\epsilon}$, which concludes the proof. $\square$

Comment: Could you explain how this leads to the desired result? The delta would imply that f(x)-L<epsilon, but we're trying to show f(x)-f(xo)<epsilon. You could break this up using the triangle inequality f(x)-f(x0)<[f(x)-L]+[L-f(xo)], but you'd need to know the value of L-f(xo), which wasn't in the limit definition .

Comment: See the edit, I've tried to do it in a clear and step-by-step way.